# C code stops after creating the first pthread (Linux)

Tags: c, linux

My code should be executing the `start_hydrogen` and `start_carbon` functions several times but only outputs to the console from execution of one thread and then the program hangs. I think I may be incorrectly starting my threads. I am new to C so let me know if additional information is needed. Note that the `this line is reached` output is printed.

```
#include "main.h"

void *start_hydrogen(void *);//executes hydrogen.c
void *start_carbon(void *);//executes carbon.c

struct threadInfo {
    int threadId;
};

struct threadInfo hydrogenIDs[NUM_H];
struct threadInfo carbonIDs[NUM_C];

int main() {
    int semid, shmid;//semaphore memory id, shared memory id
    unsigned short seminit[NUM_SEMS];//used to initialize semaphores
    struct common *shared;//pointer to shared data structure
    union semun semctlarg;//used to initialize semaphores

    pthread_t hydrogen[NUM_H];
    pthread_t carbon[NUM_C];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *exit_status;

    //Creating a set of attributes to send to the threads
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    //get semaphore memory id
    if ((semid = semget(SEMKEY, NUM_SEMS, IPC_CREAT|0777)) < 0) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("THE PROGRAM IS STARTING\n\n");

    seminit[MUTEX] = 1;//initialize mutex semaphore count to 1
    seminit[SH] = 0;//initialize hyrdrogen semaphore count to 0
    seminit[SC] = 0;//initialize carbon semaphore count to 0
    semctlarg.array = seminit;//set control array

    //apply initialization
    if ((semctl(semid, NUM_SEMS, SETALL, semctlarg)) < 0) {
        perror("semctl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //get shared memory id
    if ((shmid = shmget(SHMKEY, 1*K, IPC_CREAT|0777)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //retrieve pointer to shared data structure
    if ((shared = (struct common *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //initialize shared data structure variables
    shared->waiting_H = 0;
    shared->waiting_C = 0;

    int retVal;//used to check return value of fork()

    // spawn 20 Hydrogens
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_H; i++) {
        // if ((retVal = fork()) == 0) {
        //  hydrogen();
        //  fflush(stdout);
        //  printf("New Hydrogen process created\n");
        //  fflush(stdout);
        // } else if (retVal < 0) {
        //  perror("fork");
        //  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        // }
        hydrogenIDs[i].threadId = i;
        retVal = pthread_create(&hydrogen[i], &attr, start_hydrogen, (void*) &hydrogenIDs[i]);
        if (retVal != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("this line reached\n");

    // spawn 5 Carbons
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_C; i++) {
        // if ((retVal = fork()) == 0) {
        //  carbon();
        //  fflush(stdout);
        //  printf("New Hydrogen process created\n");
        //  fflush(stdout);
        // } else if (retVal < 0) {
        //  perror("fork");
        //  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        // }
        carbonIDs[i].threadId = i;
        retVal = pthread_create(&carbon[i], &attr, start_carbon, (void*) &carbonIDs[i]);
        if (retVal != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    //wait for all car processes to finish
    // for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    //  if (wait(0) < 0) {
    //      perror("wait");
    //      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    //  }
    // }

    //Wait for all the threads to finish
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_C; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(carbon[i], &exit_status);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_H; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(hydrogen[i], &exit_status);
    }



    printf("All atoms have crossed!\n");

        //delete semaphores
    if (semctl(semid, NUM_SEMS, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0) {
        perror("semctl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //delete shared memory
    if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0) {
        perror("shmctl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Original `start_carbon()` and `start_hydrogen()` functions

```
void *start_carbon(void* arg) {
    execl("carbon", "carbon", 0);
    perror("execl");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//if exec returns there was an error
}

void *start_hydrogen(void* arg) {
    execl("hydrogen", "hydrogen", 0);
    perror("execl");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//if exec returns there was an error
}
```

#### Modified `start_hydrogen()` and `start_carbon()` functions

After receiving feedback about the inappropriateness of using `execl()`, I changed the `start_hydrogen()` and `start_carbon()` functions to:

```
void *start_hydrogen(void* arg) {
    struct common *shared;//pointer to shared data structure

    int semid, shmid;//semaphore memory id, shared memory id

    int pid = getpid();

    //get semaphore memory id
    if ((semid = semget(SEMKEY, NUM_SEMS, 0777)) < 0) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //get shared memory id
    if ((shmid = shmget(SHMKEY, 1*K, 0777)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //get pointer to shared data structure
    if ((shared = (struct common *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // acquire lock on mutex before accessing shared memory
    semWait(semid, MUTEX);

    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Hydrogen atom, pid %d, arrives at barrier\n", pid);
    printf("Currently %d Hydrogens and %d Carbons waiting\n", shared->waiting_H + 1, shared->waiting_C);
    fflush(stdout);

    // if enough C and H is waiting, continue past barrier
    if (shared->waiting_H >= 3 
        && shared->waiting_C >= 1) {
        // release 3 H
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            semSignal(semid, SH);
        }
        shared->waiting_H -= 3;
        semSignal(semid, SC); // release 1 C
        shared->waiting_C -= 1;

        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\nHello from %d, 1 CH4 molecule has xed the barrier\n\n", pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        // release lock on mutex
        semSignal(semid, MUTEX);
    } else {
        // not enough C or H is waiting, so wait at barrier
        shared->waiting_H += 1;
        // relaese lock on mutex
        semSignal(semid, MUTEX);
        semWait(semid, SH);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *start_carbon(void* arg) {
    struct common *shared;//pointer to shared data structure

    int semid, shmid;//semaphore memory id, shared memory id

    int pid = getpid();

    //get semaphore memory id
    if ((semid = semget(SEMKEY, NUM_SEMS, 0777)) < 0) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //get shared memory id
    if ((shmid = shmget(SHMKEY, 1*K, 0777)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //get pointer to shared data structure
    if ((shared = (struct common *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // acquire lock on mutex before accessing shared memory
    semWait(semid, MUTEX);

    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Hydrogen atom, pid %d, arrives at barrier\n", pid);
    printf("Currently %d Hydrogens and %d Carbons waiting\n", shared->waiting_H + 1, shared->waiting_C);
    fflush(stdout);

    // if enough C and H is waiting, continue past barrier
    if (shared->waiting_H >= 3 
        && shared->waiting_C >= 1) {
        // release 3 H
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            semSignal(semid, SH);
        }
        shared->waiting_H -= 3;
        semSignal(semid, SC); // release 1 C
        shared->waiting_C -= 1;

        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\nHello from %d, 1 CH4 molecule has xed the barrier\n\n", pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        // release lock on mutex
        semSignal(semid, MUTEX);
    } else {
        // not enough C or H is waiting, so wait at barrier
        shared->waiting_H += 1;
        // relaese lock on mutex
        semSignal(semid, MUTEX);
        semWait(semid, SH);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You're really misusing threads here. The `execl` in each replaces the entire process with that program. When the first thread to run hits the execl, your whole process turns into your `hydrogen` process. Did you mean to fork/exec?

Comment: Yes I was originally using `fork` but wanted to migrate my code to threads

Comment: If you want code to run in a thread, don't compile it into a separate executable.

Comment: Once you have received valid answers that cover your original code, you should not destroy your question (and make the answer(s) invalid) by changing the code.  You may add to the question as shown, preserving the original, or you should accept the most helpful answer and then go on to ask a new question (which can cross-reference the original, and state that your problems are now different from what they were when the original was asked).  It is not fair to make answers invalid simply because you now have more information.

Comment: As a general tip, while trying to get the code running, think about using just 4 hydrogen threads and maybe 1 or 2 carbon threads — or some other reduced number.  Using 20 just allows there to be more confusion, unless there's a compelling reason why it requires all 20 to produce the result that's needed.  (The choice of 4 is based on a mention of CH4 somewhere in the code — use 1 or 2 hydrogen threads if you can.)

Comment: You should attach to shared memory and semaphores once, not per thread.  In fact, with threads, you don't need formal shared memory as all memory in the process is shared between threads.  You do need to ensure controlled access to the shared memory.  You might be able to use mutexes or another mechanism with threads, rather than the System V IPC semaphores.  Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  I think you should probably accept the given answer as it helped you on your way, and ask a new question with an MCVE based on what you've learned and where you are now stuck.

Comment: (Apart from a missing header `main.h` and bunch of constants, where are `semWait()` and `semSignal()` declared and defined.  I guessed values for the 9 constants — and then got a couple of compiler errors (warnings, but I use `-Werror` to convert all warnings into errors) such as `error: ordered comparison of pointer with integer zero [-Werror=extra]` for `if ((shared = (struct common *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) < 0)`, and `error: unused parameter ‘arg’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]` for  `void *start_carbon(void *arg)`. You should check for `(shared != (void *)-1)` (which is nasty but necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page for execl(),

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

and

> The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred.

If you want to use execl() to call external programs, you should fork() the parent process first to allow the parent process to continue running. Note in that case, the threads really won't do what you want.

Comment: @DanielKobe If you just want to run the program use `popen` and `pclose`. But you really don't need threads for that. You can just use a single thread and `select` or `poll`. If you want your code to run in the same process you'll need to turn it into a library.

Comment: @DanielKobe Yes... the way is to call `fork` and then `exec`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers I moved all my external code into the `start_carbon` and `start_hydrogen` functions but the functions don't print anything. `This line reached` still prints though.

Comment: @DanielKobe What's the point of calling an external program from a thread? It will run exactly the same regardless of how you call it, so what's the purpose of the thread?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I wanted to try using the `POSIX` thread library

Comment: @DanielKobe Start by looking at some simple examples of how to use threads. You won't be able to get it right by fixing issues, you have to have a core understanding of what threads and what they do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've done that but Im having difficulty with the syntax, for instance get the `pthread_create` function calls to work.